# Writing to a text file - takes 1 argument error (using Python)

Tags: python, text-files

This is my code:

```
results = [[username, score]]

with open("hisEasyR.txt","a") as hisEasyRFile:
    for result in results:
        score = result[0]
        username = result[1]
        hisEasyRFile.write(score, '|' , username , '\n')
```

I get the error:

```
hisEasyRFile.write(score, '|' , username , '\n')
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

Any idea why this is? 
Also, 'score' is an integer. Could this possible affect it? I don't believe its possible to write integers to files though is it? I need it to be an integer for future use though if I need to convert it to a string, is there any way of converting it back to a integer after I read the file?

Comment: `file.write()` is not the same as `print()`. It only takes **one string argument**.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the integer, you're passing multiple arguments (of any type) to a function that only takes 1 argument

Comment: Nothing to do with your error, but you have the assignments around the wrong way: `score = result[0]
        username = result[1]` should be `score = result[1]
        username = result[0]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be confusing `file.write()` with the `print()` function. The `file.write()` method on a text file, only accepts a **single string argument**. You can't pass in more than one value, and certainly can't pass in anything other than a string.

Either use string formatting to produce a string from multiple parts, or use the `print()` function to write to the file:

```
# assuming you expected there to be spaces between the arguments, as print() would do
# Remove those spaces around the {} placeholders if you didn't want those
hisEasyRFile.write('{} | {} \n'.format(score, username))
```

or

```
# assuming you expected there to be spaces between the arguments, as print() would do
# Add sep='' if you don't want them added. print() adds a newline
print(score, '|', username, file=hisEasyRFile)
```

The `file=...` argument to `print()` tells it to redirect the output to the file object.

If you wanted to write *character-separated values* (comma, tab, or in this case, the `|` bar character), you should really use the `csv` module instead:

```
import csv

with open("hisEasyR.txt", "a") as hisEasyRFile:
    writer = csv.writer(hisEasyRFile, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerows(results)
```

This writes all lists in one step, each with the `|` bar character between your values as separator. Conversions to string are taken care of for you. No spaces are added here.

Comment: makes mine superflous + 1

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. This is exactly the answer I was looking for but I'm getting an invalid syntax error flashing up on the `=` in `print(score, '|', username, file = hisEasyRFile)`. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Are you using Python 2? Then add `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your module. Or use `print >> hisEasyRFile, score, ‘|’, username` to use the old Python 2 syntax.